# Disable recent list in Windows 7 start menu only for certain programs

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

I know that one can disable listing recently used programs in the Windows 7 start menu. I do not want to do this. I need to disable showing recent opening only for a specific program. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back up your registry  first.

If you're referring to the frequently used programs list on the left side of the Start Menu, to stop for example winRar appearing, go to

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes\Applications\WinRAR.exe

set REG_SZ NoStartPage = 1